# Ошибка: Необработанное исключение

Tags: c++, классы, visual-c++, память

Выдает ошибку (Необработанное исключение по адресу 0x0F40FF80 (ucrtbased.dll) в ConsoleApplication3.exe: 0xC0000005: нарушение прав доступа при чтении по адресу 0x00000000) не понимаю в чем проблема. Программа прекращает работу на if()...

````
#include <iostream> 
#include <iomanip> 
#include <windows.h> 

using namespace std;

struct Continent
{
private:
    int size;
    int population;

public:
    char * name = nullptr;

    Continent() : size(0),population(0)
    {
        SetName("E");
    }
    Continent(int size) : Continent(size, population)
    {

    }
    Continent(int size, int population) : size(size), population(population)
    {

    }
    Continent(int size, int population, const char *name) : Continent(size, population)
    {
        SetName(name);
    }
    ~Continent()
    {

    }

    void SetName(const char* name)
    {
        if (strlen(this->name) != strlen(name) || name == nullptr)
        {
            delete[]name;
            this->name = new char[strlen(name) + 1];
        }
        strcpy(this->name, name);
    }

    char* GetName()
    {
        return this->name;
    }

    void SetSize(int size)
    {
        this->size = size;
    }

    int GetSize()
    {
        return this->size;
    }

    void SetPopulation(int population)
    {
        this->population = population;
    }

    int GetPopulation()
    {
        return this->population;
    }

    void Print()
    {
        cout << "Continent - " << name << "\n" << "Size - " << size
            << "\n" << "Population - " << population << "\n" << endl;
    }
};

int main()
{
    {
        Continent cont[6];
        cont[0] = Continent(10180000, 746000000, "Europe");
        cont[1] = Continent(44580000, 4561000000, "Asia");
        cont[2] = Continent(30370000, 1216000000, "Africa");
        cont[3] = Continent(9834000, 328000000, "America");
        cont[4] = Continent(8510000, 40000000, "Australia in Okeania");
        cont[5] = Continent(52000000, 4000, "Antarctic");

        cont[1].Print();
        cont[3].Print();
        cont[5].Print();

        int sumSize = 0;

        for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++)
        {
            sumSize += cont[i].GetSize();
        }

        cout << "Sum size = " << sumSize << "km^2" << endl;

        char ct[25];

        cout << endl << "Print continent name: ";
        cin >> ct;
        cout << endl;

        for (int i = 0; i < 7; i++)
        {
            int j = strcmp(ct, cont[i].GetName());
            if (j == 0)
            {
                cont[i].Print();
            }
        }
    }
    return 0;
}```
````

Answer (score 1):

Как минимум:

```
void SetName(const char* name)
{
    if (strlen(this->name) != strlen(name) || name == nullptr)
    {
        delete[]name;
        this->name = new char[strlen(name) + 1];
    }
    strcpy(this->name, name);
}
```

Здесь `name` скрывает член с тем же именем. Так что очень интересным выглядит удаление переданной строки (кстати, константного литерала, например...)

```
delete[]name
```

перед тем как ее использовать дальше.

Не говорю, что это единственная ошибка (например, в деструкторе вы не освобождаете память, в конструкторе `Continent(int size) : Continent(size, population)` происходят странные вещи, копирующий конструктор отсутствует, а сгенерированный будет неверен, используя поверхностное копирование...), но этой уже достаточно...

Comment: я пытался делать по примеру с лекции, а как сделать так чтоб оно работало вообще

Comment: Тогда вопрос надо адресовать лектору.